# Wired connection doesn't show

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, adapter, wired

thanks for read.

I haven't internet some weeks ago, i was joking with the internet configuration and now, i don't know what happen. the internet connection doesn't appaer and i can't connect to wired internet.

[image: lshr -C network]

I created a connection from system settings, but just leave me to delete it
[image: system-setting]

Some configurations:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback



mike@mike-pc:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager


root@mike-pc:/home/mike# nmcli  dev status
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION  
wlp7s0   wifi      connected    IniTics.com 
enp13s0  ethernet  unavailable  --          
lo       loopback  unmanaged    --          


root@mike-pc:/home/mike# networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 enp13s0          ether              no-carrier  unmanaged 
  3 wlp7s0           wlan               routable    unmanaged
```

i hope some of help, thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

Comment: please state exactly what you were or did then run `cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml ` and add it to your question!

Comment: Ya friend! , look it!

Comment: So what exactly did you do?

Comment: I don't remember , but it's so weird!  , the nmci show unable the netword card

Comment: Please disconnect the Wi-Fi and run `sudo networkctl status`

Comment: root@mike-pc:/home/mike# networkctl status
WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.

●        State: n/a

Comment: Now do `sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd && sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd` and then run that last command again... And why are you running as root on your Ubuntu?

Comment: I added a output with another command.
i did your command and nothing, wired network still doesn't connect :S

Comment: Now plugin your ethernet cable and lets see what happens!

Comment: Perfect, now with ifconfig , now i have a IP but internet doesn't work. 
 ( root is for don't write sudo all time while i fix the internet , thanks )

Comment: Run that `networkctl -a` and let me see the results!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86655/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-mike-brian-olivera).